# Sharepoint LIst - validation query

Tags: sharepoint-list

I've built a sharepoint list for an event and would like to allow people to select yes or no to confirm attendance.  If the answer is no, no need to complete any more questions, including compulsory ones, go straight to save.  If the answer is yes, complete the rest of the form   I've no experience with forumlae, can anyone help with a good formula for this:

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Survey might be a better solution for your requirement.

Basically you will have to

1. [Create a Survey](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-survey-ea52a787-822e-4f7e-b5ed-77bb14df3aba)
2. [Add branching logic to the survey](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-branching-logic-to-a-survey-cbd81b21-d7ba-49f3-a937-aa98e6aa5fba)

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer. Survey won't work for the particular event I am planning. We can't use Infopath so I'm stuck with Lists.